# Possible to script the "Export" command in Microsoft Outlook 2019 on Apple OS?

Tags: vba, macos, outlook, scripting, applescript

I'm trying to automate export of my calendar on Outlook 2019 on Apple OS 10.13; I don't see the Export command in the scripting dictionary of the application. Am I missing it? Is there a better way to automate this?

Comment: you posted on network engineering se a couple days ago. I think you could solve that issue with a raspberry pi and some python(or your language of choice). I'd write something for you, but I don't have access to the necessary hardware to test on, and wouldn't really know how to write the actual code for that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

What is Apple OS? Is it MacOS???
My Microsoft Outlook version is "version 16.29 (19090802)", the code below works on my MacOS 10.12.6. You can try if it works on your machine.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    activate
    delay 0.3
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Outlook"
        set theExportAsName to "Outlook for Mac Archive.olm"
        set theExportToFolder to "/Users/admin/Desktop"
        --input the file name and the destination folder path you want to export as
        tell menu item "Export..." of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
            click
            delay 0.5
        end tell
        --show the Export dialog (1/3), we need to deal with three dialogs totally.
        --knowledge point 1: how to click menu item in APP menu bar
        tell group 1 of group "What do you want to export?" of front window
            if value of radio button "Items of these types:" is not 1 then
                click radio button "Items of these types:"
            end if
        end tell
        --1st we choose export items
        tell group 1 of group 1 of group "What do you want to export?" of front window
            if value of checkbox "Mail" is not 0 then
                click checkbox "Mail"
            end if
            if value of checkbox "Calendar" is not 1 then
                click checkbox "Calendar"
            end if
            if value of checkbox "Contacts " is not 0 then
                click checkbox "Contacts "
            end if
        end tell
        tell group 2 of group 1 of group "What do you want to export?" of front window
            if value of checkbox "Notes" is not 0 then
                click checkbox "Notes"
            end if
            if value of checkbox "Tasks" is not 0 then
                click checkbox "Tasks"
            end if
        end tell
        --2nd we check Calendar, uncheck all the others
        click button "Continue" of front window
        delay 0.5
        --3rd click Continue button to go to next dialog window (2/3)
        tell text field 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            set value to theExportAsName
        end tell
        --1st we set the file name we want to use
        set the clipboard to theExportToFolder
        keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
        delay 0.5
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
        delay 0.5
        keystroke return
        delay 0.5
        --2nd we set the destination folder path we want to use
        tell sheet 1 of front window
            click button "Save"
            delay 0.5
        end tell
        --3rd click Save button to go to the last dialog window (3/3)
        tell front window
            click button "Finish"
        end tell
        --1st click Finish button to finish this task
    end tell
end tell
```

Note 1:    the delay duration is longer than needed, I set it to big number to make the code run slowly, to make you see what happened. You can test then set smaller delay value to speed up the running.

Note 2:    to these three dialog window, I all use the code below to get information about the UI elements - to see how to reference them.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    activate
    delay 0.3
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Outlook"
        tell front window
            set uiElems to entire contents
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Note 3:    I write some comments to explain each step of the code. You can test it on your machine. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you!!! This is amazing. Yes it works almost perfectly - it kickstarts the export, and then immediately gives this error:          System Events got an error: Can’t get button "Finish" of window 1 of process "Microsoft Outlook".

Comment: Sorry, didn't finish typing.   Is there a way to get rid of the error - maybe a wait before it tries to hit the Finish button?   And, is it possible to sequentially append a number to the savefile name, so that it doesn't over-write the previous one if I have it do this nightly?

Comment: @MikeLevin 1st: This code works perfectly on my machine. The error you mentioned, you can run the code in Note 2 in my post to analysis the third dialog window to see how to reference the Finish button on your machine. 2nd : Since we only want to click Finish button on this window, you can try use "keystroke return" at this step. 3rd: how to save file with increment number is a very old question. You can find a lot of information on Google. I cannot do all the things for you. Cause you can learn a lot and have a lot of fun in troubleshooting in coding.

Comment: Thank you. I ran your Note 2 code after the menu came up, but I'm not sure how to use this information to dispel the error. I'll post the output in 2 Comments, since it's a bit too long to be allowed in one.

Comment: {static text "Your data has been exported." of window "Export to Archive File (.olm)" of application process "Microsoft Outlook" of application "System Events", image 1 of window "Export to Archive File (.olm)" of application process "Microsoft Outlook" of application "System Events", button "Finish" of window "Export to Archive File (.olm)" of

Comment: application process "Microsoft Outlook" of application "System Events", button "Export More" of window "Export to Archive File (.olm)" of application process "Microsoft Outlook" of application "System Events", static text "Export to Archive File (.olm)" of window "Export to Archive File (.olm)" of application process "Microsoft Outlook" of application "System Events"}

Comment: I've also tried:  
 
 delay 700
  tell front window
   keystroke return
  end tell
  --1st click Finish button to finish this task
and that hasn't worked either. No error, but the final menu doesn't disappear.